# Using map for storage while accessing with baseclass?

Tags: c++, dictionary, inheritance

I'm using an `std::map` for *storage* (storing data on the stack).

This *map* is happened to store *items* which are derived instances of a *base* class:

```
class Base {
public:
int id;

  Base(int id): id(id) {}
  void baseFn() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived(int id): Base(id) {}
};


std::map<int, Derived> storage;
```

My question is more *theoretical* than *practical* (as I know a few solutions):

I **have to** pass this *storage* to a function (`register_cb`) requires `void*` as its parameter. This function is not owned by me, and I can't change it.

Later, a callback function (`cb`) will pass me this pointer, and I wish to use it to get back my *storage*:

```
//void register_cb(void* data);
register_cb(&storage);

void cb(void* data) {
  //get back my storage
  std::map<int, Derived>* storage = static_cast<std::map<int, Derived>*>(data);
}
```

Now this is a bit ugly, but anyway it *works*.

What I wish to accomplish is to access the storage from callbacks where I don't know the Derived class, only the Base:

I wish to iterate through the map, and call `baseFn` on every single item. Can I somehow **safely** cast `std::map<int, Derived>` to `std::map<int, Base pointer or reference or whatever>`?

Comment: No, this conversion is not possible. Containers of related types are not related.

Comment: *"using an std::map for storage (storing data on the stack)."* `std::map` always stores the elements on the heap, unless you use a custom allocator.

Comment: Or you have a freaky system that uses hamster wheels for dynamic storage instead of a heap.

Comment: What I wished to express is that `std::map` is handling the *ownership*.

Comment: Yes, `cb`  has no idea about the `derived`, but I'm sure the `void*` is a map holding items whose baseclass is base.

Comment: @Daniel You would need to define a second map, where the value type is a `Base*`, such that each key's value points to the corresponding key's value in the original map.

Comment: Have you yet considered a redesign from `std::map<int, Derived>` to`std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Base> >`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I think it won't survive the callback mechanism if I declare it inside a function just before the *register_cb* call.

Comment: @AviBerger: yes, of course, that's definitely one good way to go.

Comment: The only other idea besides @FrançoisAndrieux's that I see at the moment is to try to do something with a discriminated union. That would be messy and prone to be broken by future code changes, though. Probably not a good way to go.